Async route in Deno and fresh
I want to do this in my async route, which will be used as a component:
interface MyProps{
  myName: string;
}
export default async function MyComponent(req: Request, ctx: RouteContext,  props: MyProps) {
const lookedUp = await myDB.find(props.myName);
return <div>{lookedup}</div>
}

But when I import MyComponent I get

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Request'

export default function MyCallingComponent() {
  return <div>Found some dogs <MyComponent myName="cheese"/></div>
}

I tried to import my custom component, but vs code is giving me a syntax error.  Do I need to include request and context somehow?

I, don't think it's possible to use a route as a component, nor are there async components.
